# Ajax post a form to controller (store) in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I managed to create a form that post data in PHP to a store controller. It worked well but now I try to convert it so that it could make an Ajax request instead.

I can't make it work. When I click submit, I got no message, no page refresh and no data is stored. The network tab of the Google CHrome developer tools show that the browser makes a Post request to the Leads controller. Here is what I got, what is wrong?

**create.blade.php (view)**

```
{{ Form::open(['route'=>'leads.store', 'method'=>'post', 'class'=>'formcontainer', 'id'=>'leadscreate']) }}

{{ Form::label('nomopportunite','Nom du lead')}}
{{ Form::text('nomopportunite', '', array('id'=>'nomopportunite1', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Nom du lead')) }}

{{ Form::label('statut','Statut')}}
{{ Form::select('statut', array('1' => 'Premier contact', '2' => 'En négociation', '3' => 'Fermé - Gagné', '4' => 'Fermé - Perdu'), '', array('id'=>'statut1')) }}

{{ Form::label('valeur','Valeur')}}
{{ Form::text('valeur', '', array('id'=>'valeur1', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Valeur ($)')) }}

{{ Form::submit('Ajouter', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**javascript ajax part**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#leadscreate').on('submit', function(){ 

    $.post(
        $(this).prop('action'),        {
            "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
            "nomopportunite": $( '#nomopportunite1' ).val(),
            "statut": $( '#statut1' ).val(),
            "valeur": $( '#valeur1' ).val()
        },
        function(data){
            //response after the process. 
        },
        'json'
    ); 
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

LeadsController.php (store)

```
public function store() {
    if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
        return Response::json( array(
            'msg' => 'Erreur!'
        ) );
    }

    $nomopportunite = Input::get( 'nomopportunite' );
    $statut = Input::get( 'statut' );  
    $valeur = Input::get( 'valeur' );        

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'L\'opportunité a bien été ajoutée!',
    );

    return Response::json( $response );
}
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the response from the ajax function?

Comment: When I click on the button, nothing happens. No page refresh, no message and no data is stored in the database.

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: There are no errors, I checked ;)

Comment: To debug it, just remove `if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) )` and check the result, also, make sure that, `store` method is being invoked and make sure this method is mapped to a route with `Route::post()` declaration.

Comment: Where did you create a new entry in your `store` method, in your code I don't see anything that may create a new entry in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to The Alpha for pointing out that there was something missing in my controller.  I modified my controller to this and now it works (data is saved in the databse). Hope it will help.

```
public function store() {
    if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
        return Response::json( array(
            'msg' => 'Erreur!'
        ) );
    }      

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'L\'opportunité a bien été ajoutée!',
    );

    $rules = array(
        'nomopportunite'       => 'required',
        'statut'               => 'required',
        'valeur'               => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        $lead = new Lead;
        $lead->nomopportunite       = Input::get('nomopportunite');
        $lead->statut               = Input::get('statut');
        $lead->valeur               = Input::get('valeur');
        $lead->save();

        return Response::json( $response );

    }
}
```

and I also modified my jQuery script to give the user a feedback:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#leadscreate').on('submit', function(){ 

    $.post(
        $(this).prop('action'),        {
            "_token": $( this ).find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),
            "nomopportunite": $( '#nomopportunite1' ).val(),
            "statut": $( '#statut1' ).val(),
            "valeur": $( '#valeur1' ).val()
        },
        function($response){
            $('#messagetop').slideToggle();
        },
        'json'
    ); 
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It says I can in two days.

Comment: I did not take in account StackOverflow bureaucracy.